# Error inheriting FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy

Tags: caching, token, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the facebook-ios SDK 3.0 into my app - and I'm using rails/devise as the back end of my app to manage users.

Right now I'm trying to derive a custom class of [FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy as suggested here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy)

The issue is when I try to inherit this class in a subclass like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface CustomFBSessionTokenCachingStrategy : FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy

@end
```

I get the following error "Attempting to use the forward class 'FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy' as superclass of 'CustomFBSessionTokenCachingStrategy'"

This might be a really silly error on my part - and if so I apologise - but I'm stuck as to why I cannot inherit this class! If someone could point me in the right direction here I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy.h` is not included in `FacebookSDK.h`.
You need to add its import:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy.h>

@interface CustomFBSessionTokenCachingStrategy : FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy

@end
```